# How can I utilize my scrollbar in my code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on our final project in our school using Tkinter Python. However, an error occured where I can't use my scrollbar in my code. The program is working but I can't scroll down to see my other buttons.
[image: output]

As you can see in the image, buttons are working. However, I can't scroll up/down in the area where the buttons are located (the peach color part of the output).

Starting from 'def save_name():', I can't utilize the scrollbar anymore.
Here's the code below:

```py
def save_name():
    global logo_pic
    name = name_entry.get()
    window2.destroy()
    window3 = Toplevel()
    window3.title("Easy Cart")
    window3.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    window3.geometry('720x800')
    window3.resizable(False, False)
    window3.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    window3.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    main_frame = Frame(window3)
    main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    
    my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, bg='#FFC2A6')
    my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    
    scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL,
                              command=my_canvas.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar)
    my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))
    
    second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
    my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame)
    
    
    
    display_text = Label(window3, text="Welcome to Easy Cart " 
                         + name + "!", font=("Segoe Script", 10,
                                             "bold italic"), bg='#FFC2A6')
    display_text.pack()
    display_text.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.12, anchor=CENTER)
    
    canvas = Canvas(window3, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(window3, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)
    


def baking_command():
    baking_window = Toplevel()
    baking_window.title("Easy Cart")
    baking_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    baking_window.geometry('720x800')
    baking_window.resizable(False, False)
    baking_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    baking_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(baking_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(baking_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

baking_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("baking needs.png").resize((150, 150)))
baking = Button(window3, image=baking_pic, command=baking_command)
baking.image = baking_pic
baking.pack()
baking.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.15)

def beverage_command():
    beverage_window = Toplevel()
    beverage_window.title("Easy Cart")
    beverage_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    beverage_window.geometry('720x800')
    beverage_window.resizable(False, False)
    beverage_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    beverage_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(beverage_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(beverage_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

beverage_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("beverages.png").resize((150, 150)))
beverage = Button(window3, image=beverage_pic, command=beverage_command)
beverage.image = beverage_pic
beverage.pack()
beverage.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.15)

def canned_command():
    canned_window = Toplevel()
    canned_window.title("Easy Cart")
    canned_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    canned_window.geometry('720x800')
    canned_window.resizable(False, False)
    canned_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    canned_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(canned_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(canned_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

canned_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("canned goods.png").resize((150, 150)))
canned = Button(window3, image=canned_pic, command=canned_command)
canned.image = canned_pic
canned.pack()
canned.place(relx=0.75,rely=0.15)

def condiments_command():
    condiments_window = Toplevel()
    condiments_window.title("Easy Cart")
    condiments_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    condiments_window.geometry('720x800')
    condiments_window.resizable(False, False)
    condiments_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    condiments_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(condiments_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(condiments_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

condiments_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("condiments.png").resize((150, 150)))
condiments = Button(window3, image=condiments_pic, command=condiments_command)
condiments.image = condiments_pic
condiments.pack()
condiments.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.40)

def dairy_command():
    dairy_window = Toplevel()
    dairy_window.title("Easy Cart")
    dairy_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    dairy_window.geometry('720x800')
    dairy_window.resizable(False, False)
    dairy_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    dairy_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(dairy_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(dairy_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

dairy_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("dairy.png").resize((150, 150)))
dairy = Button(window3, image=dairy_pic, command=dairy_command)
dairy.image = dairy_pic
dairy.pack()
dairy.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.40)

def detergents_command():
    detergents_window = Toplevel()
    detergents_window.title("Easy Cart")
    detergents_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    detergents_window.geometry('720x800')
    detergents_window.resizable(False, False)
    detergents_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    detergents_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(detergents_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(detergents_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

detergents_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("detergents.png").resize((150, 150)))
detergents = Button(window3, image=detergents_pic, command=detergents_command)
detergents.image = detergents_pic
detergents.pack()
detergents.place(relx=0.75,rely=0.40)

def fruits_command():
    fruits_window = Toplevel()
    fruits_window.title("Easy Cart")
    fruits_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    fruits_window.geometry('720x800')
    fruits_window.resizable(False, False)
    fruits_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    fruits_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(fruits_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(fruits_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

fruits_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("fruits.png").resize((150, 150)))
fruits = Button(window3, image=fruits_pic, command=fruits_command)
fruits.image = fruits_pic
fruits.pack()
fruits.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.65)

def health_command():
    health_window = Toplevel()
    health_window.title("Easy Cart")
    health_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    health_window.geometry('720x800')
    health_window.resizable(False, False)
    health_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    health_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(health_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(health_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

health_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("health.png").resize((150, 150)))
health = Button(window3, image=health_pic, command=health_command)
health.image = health_pic
health.pack()
health.place(relx=0.4,rely=0.65)

def laundry_command():
    laundry_window = Toplevel()
    laundry_window.title("Easy Cart")
    laundry_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    laundry_window.geometry('720x800')
    laundry_window.resizable(False, False)
    laundry_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    laundry_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(laundry_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(laundry_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

laundry_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("laundry aids.png").resize((150, 150)))
laundry = Button(window3, image=laundry_pic, command=laundry_command)
laundry.image = laundry_pic
laundry.pack()
laundry.place(relx=0.75,rely=0.65)

def meats_command():
  meats_window = Toplevel()
  meats_window.title("Easy Cart")
  meats_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
  meats_window.geometry('720x800')
  meats_window.resizable(False, False)
  meats_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
  meats_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
  
  canvas = Canvas(meats_window, width=800, height=70)
  canvas.pack()
  canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
  logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
  logo = Label(meats_window, image=logo_pic)
  logo.pack()
  logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)
  
meats_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("meats.png").resize((150, 150)))
meats = Button(window3, image=meats_pic, command=meats_command)
meats.image = meats_pic
meats.pack()
meats.place(relx=0.05,rely=0.90)

def oats_command():
  oats_window = Toplevel()
  oats_window.title("Easy Cart")
  oats_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
  oats_window.geometry('720x800')
  oats_window.resizable(False, False)
  oats_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
  oats_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
  
  canvas = Canvas(oats_window, width=800, height=70)
  canvas.pack()
  canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
  logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
  logo = Label(oats_window, image=logo_pic)
  logo.pack()
  logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)
  
oats_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("oats.png").resize((150, 150)))
oats = Button(window3, image=oats_pic, command=oats_command)
oats.image = oats_pic
oats.pack()
oats.place(relx=0.40,rely=0.90)

def oil_command():
    oil_window = Toplevel()
    oil_window.title("Easy Cart")
    oil_window.iconbitmap('icon.ico')
    oil_window.geometry('720x800')
    oil_window.resizable(False, False)
    oil_window.configure(bg='#FFC2A6')
    oil_window.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    
    canvas = Canvas(oil_window, width=800, height=70)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.place(relx=0, rely=0)
    logo_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png").resize((50, 50)))
    logo = Label(oil_window, image=logo_pic)
    logo.pack()
    logo.place(relx=0.47,rely=0.015)

oil_pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("oil.png").resize((150, 150)))
oil = Button(window3, image=oil_pic, command=oil_command)
oil.image = oil_pic
oil.pack()
oil.place(relx=0.75,rely=0.90)
```

I expect that I can scroll down to view other buttons below. I want to have a scrollbar in the peach color region of my code where the buttons are located.

Comment: Please try to reduce the size of your example code. It’s way too long. See [mcve] for help.

Comment: There is nothing in the `second_frame`, so the `scrollregion` is smaller than the size of the canvas. That is why the scrollbar not activated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def on_mouse_wheel(event):
    my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 120), "units")
```

//bind the mouse wheel event to the function for the 'my_canvas' object. Use the event string for your OS or all of them i guess

```
my_canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", on_mouse_wheel)  # Windows
my_canvas.bind("<Button-4>", on_mouse_wheel)  # Linux
my_canvas.bind("<Button-5>", on_mouse_wheel)  # Also Linux
```

---

```
def save_name():
    def on_mouse_wheel(event):
        my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int(event.delta / 120), "units")

  logo_pic
```

//ur code

```
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion=my_canvas.bbox("all")))

#event bind
my_canvas.bind("<MouseWheel>", on_mouse_wheel)  # For Windows
my_canvas.bind("<Button-4>", on_mouse_wheel)  # For Linux
my_canvas.bind("<Button-5>", on_mouse_wheel)  # For Linux
```

good luck o.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).